# Combinatorial problem - 6 classic dice

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

Can anyone help me with this task?

We throw with $6$ classic (cubical) dice. Two are yellow, two are blue and two are green. After every throw, we put them into a line. How many different lines exist if we distinguish colors and the values?

I think that answer is $$1440\text{ (options for yellow)}\times1440\text{ (options for blue)}\times1440\text{ (options for green).}$$ But sadly, I don't think that this is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you get $1440$ options for e.g. yellow?

Answer (score 1):

First, independent of the colours, we can have $6^6$ arrangements of eyes. (Number of values a die can take to the power of the number of dice.) In addition to this, you need to consider the arrangement of colours. If you first distribute two dice (e.g. yellow) to the $6$ slots, you get $(5+4+3+2+1)$ arrangements. Then, when you distribute the next pair (e.g. blue) to the $4$ remaining slots, there are $(3+2+1)$ ways. And the final pair has to fit in the remaining two slots.

In total that makes

$$6^6(5+4+3+2+1)(3+2+1) = 4199040$$

possible arrangements.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Observe that the number of color arrangements can also be obtained (perhaps more systematically) as the multinomial expression $\binom{6}{2, 2, 2} = \frac{6!}{(2!)(2!)(2!)} = \frac{720}{8} = 90$, which is the same value as $15 \times 6$, of course.

Comment: This is of course a great tool, but in this case I thought it might be an overkill, but now we have both ways here, which is even better=)